# Cannot read property 'wrapDateLine' of null - OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

My code is giving the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrapDateLine' of null OpenLayers.js:192
OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.isValidLonLat OpenLayers.js:192
OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.moveTo OpenLayers.js:187
OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.setCenter OpenLayers.js:184
init chapter_8_ex9_using_multiple_maps_custom_event_app.html:38
onload chapter_8_ex9_using_multiple_maps_custom_event_app.html:63`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
 var map1, map2;
 //FunÃ§Ã£o a ser chamada para criar o mapa na leitura da pÃ¡gina
 function init() {
  map_1 = new OpenLayers.Map('map_1_element', {
    controls: [
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()
    ],
    maxResolution:0.0054931640625,
    minResolution:0.00034332275390625
    });
//Create a base layer
var wms_layer_all = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    'OpenLayers WMS',
    'http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0',
    {layers: 'basic'},
    {}
);
//Variável para mudar o ponto central do mapa
var map_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-120, 34);

if(!map_1.getCenter()){
    map_1.setCenter(map_center)
};          
 //Cria o segundo  mapa
map_2 = new OpenLayers.Map('map_2_element', {
    controls: [
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()
    ],
    maxResolution: 0.17578125,
    minResolution: 0.0439453125
});
 var wms_layer_all_map_2 = wms_layer_all.clone();
 map_2.addLayer(wms_layer_all_map_2);
 map_2.setCenter(map_center); 
 if(!map_2.getCenter()){
     map_2.zoomToMaxExtent();
     };
 };
 </script>
</head>
<body onload='init();'> 
<div id='map_1_element' style='height:500px; float:left; width:400px;'></div>
<div id='map_2_element' style='height:500px; float:left; width:400px;'></div>
<div style='clear:both;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `wms_layer_all` layer, on the first map:

```js
map_1.addLayer(wms_layer_all);

//Variável para mudar o ponto central do mapa
var map_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-120, 34);
```

Then, everything will be ok:

[image]